# misuse of the if statement?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm very new to android and am stuck with something very simple. I'm trying to state that for a variable x (can be a, b or c), there is a corresponding integer value (i.e. 0, 1 and 2)

```
    String mpee = x;
          int mpef = 0;
          int mpev = 0;

        if (mpee == "a") { mpef = mpev + 0; }
        if (mpee == "b") { mpef = mpev + 1; }
        if (mpee == "c") { mpef = mpev + 2; }

       int mpp = mpef;
```

The output will be int mpp. There is no problem with the code as far as Eclipse is concerned, but when I run it, the application hangs. The following is the logcat.

```
06-05 13:29:49.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 13:29:49.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.exa.huy/com.example.exa.huy}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
String resource ID #0x0
06-05 13:29:49.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
06-05 13:29:49.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
06-05 13:29:49.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-05 13:29:49.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-05 13:29:49.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 13:29:49.014: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The exception is caused by the fact that you try to use an int as resource-id which doesn't exists. Another errors you do is how you compare strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: post peace of code where you are trying to perform this operation

Comment: use equalignore case instead of "==" in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must alter the way you are comparing strings - as String is an object, it has a built in compare method equals(), in which the input is a string you want to compare your string too. Using `==` compares if they are the same object rather than if their strings match, which does not seem like what you intended to do. Also, an `if-else` block might work better than 3 extra statements, as if an `if` condition is filled it will not bother to check the rest, and in your case will work as each condition is mutually exclusive.

```
String mpee = x;
      int mpef = 0;
      int mpev = 0;

    if (mpee.equals("a")) { mpef = mpev + 0; }
    else if (mpee.equals("b")) { mpef = mpev + 1; }
    else if (mpee.equals("c")) { mpef = mpev + 2; }

   int mpp = mpef;
```

From the LogCat it looks like you are called a reference you can't find. Please post more of your code so we can figure out just exactly what the error is. In this case, it seems like you are calling a reference with the integer value `0`, which doesn't exist. Are you trying to reference a certain View in your layout?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works perfectly just as I hope it would.

Comment: It I might add, does it make any difference to use if(){}, if(){}, if(){} or better to use the one you use above if(){} else if(){} else if(){}

Comment: Essentially, the task you need in this scenario will be completed either way - because `mpee` can only hold one value (and in this case it will be a, b, or c), only one of the `if` statements will go off. However, in general if you have mutually exclusive checks (such as _will a value be_ a, b, or c rather than _will a value contain_ a, b, or c), `if-else` statements will stop unnecessary code from being executed, and overall increase the performance of your program.

Comment: Thanks. Straight to the point and easy to understand. I appreciate it.